# How to do an event forecasting such as flood forecasting using machine learning algorithm?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining

I got stuck about doing a forecasting of flood using machine learning algorithm. My current ML algorithm is decision tree and I want to predict the flood disaster or an event that probably happened in future. So I have X input such as maximum themperature, humidity, rainfall, wind speed, and so on and my label target is flood event.

Answer (score 0):

Machine learning is a bad choice here.

these approaches are good at predicting common behavior from plenty of training examples.

They are not at all good at predicting extremes such as never seen before or at least rare floods.

For that, please use statistics, in particular **extreme value theory**.